# React Native how to get cookie

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, express, cookies

I have a cookie-based auth system, and I don't understand how to get cookie from react native/expo. I use `js-cookie` library for managing cookie.

The request method:

```
async  postData(url = '', data) {
      // Default options are marked with *
      const response = await fetch(url, {
        method: 'POST', // *GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, etc.
        mode: 'cors', // no-cors, *cors, same-origin
        cache: 'no-cache', // *default, no-cache, reload, force-cache, only-if-cached
        credentials: 'same-origin', // include, *same-origin, omit
        headers: {
          'Content-Type': 'application/json',
          "CSRF-Token": Cookies.get("XSRF-TOKEN")
        },
        redirect: 'follow', // manual, *follow, error
        referrerPolicy: 'no-referrer', // no-referrer, *no-referrer-when-downgrade, origin, origin-when-cross-origin, same-origin, strict-origin, strict-origin-when-cross-origin, unsafe-url
        body: JSON.stringify({data}) // body data type must match "Content-Type" header
      });

      return response.json(); // parses JSON response into native JavaScript objects
}
```

when I `consoloe.log(Cookies.get("XSRF-TOKEN"))` it shows `undefined`.

This is my express backend:

```
app.use(csrf({cookie: true}))
app.use("*", (req, res, next)=>{
    res.cookie("XSRF-TOKEN", req.csrfToken());
    next();
})
```

Answer (score 0):

To get cookies in an expo project, you will first have to eject and then you can access the cookies for Android and iOS separately, as expo does not have any module that can help you get cookies.

Comment: Can i again re bundle the project to expo after doing that?

Comment: I heard about async storage. How do i transform this to async storage?

Comment: After you eject, all your JS files will stay the same, but we'll additionally create ios and android directories in your project folder. You'll still be able to develop and test your project with Expo CLI, and you'll still be able to publish your Expo JS code the same way. Hope this works for you.

Comment: @Rohan_157, could you share some code for android and ios for ejected project?